# Insert blank row in colour after each date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a full blank row (No formulas, preferably in colour) after each time the date changes in excel.

My data looks like this : 
[image: Data Pic]

I have put in my own code, it works but I get run-time error 13 type mismatch after the macro runs.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is the code I Have used

Comment: Sub Newblankrow()
'NLC Data split after each date Macro
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Int(Range("A" & i).Value) <> Int(Range("A" & i - 1).Value) Then
        Range("A" & i).Rows.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Sub Newblankrow()
'NLC Data split after each date Macro
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Int(Range("A" & i).Value) <> Int(Range("A" & i - 1).Value) Then
        Range("A" & i).Rows.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Don't add new information in the comments. Add it to your original post instead, with the proper code formatting

Comment: Adding your code to the post description helps people to understand your problem and help you solve the issue. Add your code to the post itself, it is a good information to help you and it is readable. Nothing can be understood in comments.

Comment: In order to add the code (and any additional information) to the question itself, use the [edit] link below the question.

Answer (score 0):

@WayneP, try to make something like this:

```
Public Sub InsertBlankRow()

On Error GoTo erro

Dim active_row As Long
Dim last_row As Long

    Worksheets("Planilha1").Activate

looping:
    last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For active_row = 3 To last_row

        If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row).Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row - 1).Value Then

            If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row).Value <> "" And ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row + 1).Value <> "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Rows(active_row & ":" & active_row).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                active_row = active_row + 1
                GoTo looping

            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row).Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Range("A" & active_row + 1).Value <> "" Then
                active_row = active_row + 1

            End If

        End If
    Next active_row

Exit Sub

erro: MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error at InsertBlankRow()"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help:

Comment: but when I run that Macro I get "9:Subscript out of range" Error

Comment: Try to change  the code line:

    Worksheets("Planilha1").Activate

To it:

    Worksheets("Your sheet name").Activate

Hope this helps...